# Can't get @media query settings inside CSS file to execute in applicable platforms

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I wrote the CSS code for the desktop version of my website in my website's style.css file. Then, at the end of the css file, I wrote

```
body, html {    /*the outer layer of the site and global style attributes*/
    font-family: "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    margin: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 100%; /*16px*/
    background-color: #383c5f;
    /*background-image: linear-gradient(#191e4d, white);*/
    display: flex;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;

    }
/*    
* { 
    border: 1px solid red; 
} */

#website {
    width: 100%;   
}

#logo {
    height: 20px;
}


/* NAV BAR */
.nav-bar {
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    display: flex;
    background-color: #232754;
    flex-direction: horizontal;
    justify-content: center;
    z-index: 3;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-bar-item {
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    font-family: Lucida Grande, sans-serif;
    color: white;
    font-size: /*1.40vw*/ 1.25em;
    padding-top: 7px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;  
    margin-top: 1.75vh;
}

img {
    height: 100%;
    left: 50%
}


/* Slideshow */
* {
    box-sizing: border-box
}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
    max-width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    height: 85%;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    top: -1.5%;
}

/* Hide the images by default */
.mySlides {
  display: none;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -22px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.125em;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

/* Caption text */
.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Number text (1/4 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 2.5%;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active, .dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

/*Content*/

.content {
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.title {
    position: absolute;
    left: 16%;
    font-size: /*3em*/ 6vh;
    color: white;
    font-family: Futura, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 8px 8px 10px #000000;
}

/*HOMEPAGE*/

.container {
    width: 80%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: horizontal;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.container.home {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: horizontal;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

#name {
    font-family: 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: /*8.75em*/ 9.75vw;
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -105%);
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 8px 8px 10px #000000;
    display: none;
}

#quote {
    font-family: 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: /*2.5em*/ 2.75vw;
    color:/* #191e4d;*/ white;
    position: absolute;
    top: 70%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
    -webkit-text-stroke: 1px #5d4f4f;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 8px 8px 10px #000000;
    display: none;
}


/*ABOUT*/

.title.about{
    top: 118%;
}

.about-item {
    margin: 30px;
    width: 350px;
    height: 350px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: horizontal;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}


#kristy-picture{
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 80% /*20vw*/;
    height: 80% /*20vw*/;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 100%;
}

#resume-line {
    position: absolute;
    font-size: /*1.5em*/ 3.25vh;
    color: /*#191e4d;*/ white;
    top: 180%;
    font-family: Futura, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;

}

#rlink:link {
    color: white;
}

#rlink:active {
    color: rgb(228, 235, 250);
}
#rlink:visited {
    color: rgb(186, 206, 250);
}

#about-description {
    color: white;
    font-family: Futura, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.125em;
}

/* PROJECTS */

.title.projects{
    top: 218%;
}

#projects-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: inherit;
    height: 65%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 235%;   
    align-items: center;
}

.project {
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 50%;
    width: 35%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-around;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 5px;
    background: #333454;
    align-items: center;
    /* box-shadow: 4px 4px 4px #000000a8; */
    border-color: white;
}

#byow-img:hover {
    animation: enlarge_photo ease-in 0.5s;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
}

#bearmaps-img:hover {
    animation: enlarge_photo ease-in 0.5s;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
}


#maps-img:hover {
   /* box-shadow: 8px 8px 8px #000000a8;*/
    animation: enlarge_photo ease-in 0.5s;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
}

@keyframes enlarge_photo {
    from {
        width: 85%;
        height: 75%
    }


    to {
        width: 95%;
        height: 85%;
    }
}


.proj-image{
    width: 85%;
    height: 7M5%;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.proj-label {
    color: #f2f2f2;
    font-family: Futura, sans-serif;

}

/* EXPERIENCE */
.title.experience{
    top: 318%;
}

#experience-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-around;
    /* flex-wrap: wrap; */
    width: inherit;
    height: 65%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 330%;
    align-items: center;
}

.expr-item {
    height: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: horizontal;
    justify-content: center;
    /*overflow: scroll;*/
    margin: 5px;
    align-items: center;
    border-width: 2px;
    background-color: #35395d;
    border-color: #1f2140;
}

#skills {
    /* height: 70%; */
    /* width: 35%; */
    /* border-radius: 30px; */
    border-width: 2px;
    background-color: #35395d;
    border-color: #1f2140;
    color: white;
    font-family: Futura, sans-serif;
    display: flex;
}
/*
#exp-flex {
    height: 65%;
    width: 60%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-around;
}*/

.tex sub, .latex sub, .latex sup {
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }

  .tex sub, .latex sub {
    vertical-align: -0.5ex;
    margin-left: -0.1667em;
    margin-right: -0.125em;
  }

  .tex, .latex, .tex sub, .latex sub {
    font-size: 1em;
  }

  .latex sup {
    font-size: 0.85em;
    vertical-align: 0.15em;
    margin-left: -0.36em;
    margin-right: -0.15em;
  }

.textbox {
    width: 75%;
    height: 80%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: 0.875em;
    color: white;
    font-family: Futura, sans-serif;
}

.exp-image {
    width: 10%;
    height: 75%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
}

/* CONTACT ME */

.title.contact{
    top: 418%;
}

#contact-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: inherit;
    height: 65%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 430%;
    align-items: center;
}

#contact-line {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    color: white;
    font-family: Futura, sans-serif;
}

.contact-box-container {
    width: 80%;
    height: 60%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
}

.contact-box {
    width: 40%;
    height: 80%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: /*rgb(112, 129, 184)*/ #333454;
    border-color: #1f2140;
    border-width: 2px;
    color: white;
    font-family: Futura, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;

}


/* Popup Box */
#overlay {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    position: absolute;
    height: 500%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}

#lightbox {
    display: none;
}

#specific-project-container {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    z-index: 3;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background-color: #1e2435;
    height: 82%;
    width: 70%;
    border-color: #1e1e54;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-width: 3px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    overflow: scroll;
}

.picture {
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 45%;
    height: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;

}
.proj-desc {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 80%;
    /*overflow: scroll; */
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    color: white;
    font-family: Futura, sans-serif;

}
/* BOTTOM BAR */

.bottom-bar {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: horizontal;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: flex-end;
    margin-bottom: 40px;


}

.bottom-button {
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block; 
    opacity: 0.6;
    z-index: 1;

}

.bottom-button:hover {
    animation: opaque ease-in 0.3s;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
   /* opacity: 1;*/
}

@keyframes opaque {
    from { opacity: 0.6; }
    to { opacity: 1}
}

#copyright {
    font-size: 0.75em;
    position: fixed;
    color: /*#191e4d;*/ white;
    margin-bottom: 48px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    z-index: 1;


}

@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    #kristy-picture {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }

    #about-description {
        color: white;
        font-family: Futura, sans-serif;
        font-size: 1.5em;
    }

    .project {
        height: 30%;
    }

    .exp-image {
        width: 20%;
        height: 30%;
    }

    .contact-box-container {
        width: 100%;
        height: 40%;
    }

}

@media only screen and (max-height: 520px) {
    .textbox {
        font-size: 0.5em;
    }
}
```

to override any of the existing above elements' settings for mobile display. I'm not sure why these settings aren't showing up on my iPhone when I view my website, though. Am I not supposed to put @media at the end of my file? I used this YouTube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2KL-z9A56SQ to learn about responsive design from desktop to downwards.

Comment: I don't see any problem in this piece here. There might something else which causing the error , would you mind providing the detailed code ?

Comment: Are you sure you are targeting the elements in your media query the same way you are targeting them above? Also, try writing your query as `@media screen only and...` (include `only`)

Comment: @AjaySharma Just updated the post with the full code.

Comment: @Claire Did so, settings don't translate properly to iPhone mobile.

Comment: Btw, the link to website is kristyelee.github.io. Am not adding bootstrap because the website is probably not high on my list of things to do over summer. But I just want to fix the layout a little bit on iPhone, but even the simplest changes aren't translating properly.

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE], CSS is pretty meaningless without the accompanying HTML. Also note "minimal" , by reducing the problem to a smaller size, it will be easier to debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just checked your website and it seems that you are missing meta-tags in your web page. `<meta>` viewport element tells the browser about the page's dimensions and scaling. Include the following tag in your `<head>` tag and everything will work as expected.

```
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

You can follow [this link](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_meta.asp) to know more about meta tags and their importance on a web page. Hope it Helps.

Comment: Hmm interesting, I get what it's supposed to do, but I tried to add it and it didn't work out properly. The website's font picture etc became disproportionately large relative to screen

Comment: Did you inspect your code? You will see the media queries in effect now and the disproportions you are talking about is because of your css. Once you fix it, everything will be fixed. Hence this question is only to make your media queries work . Right?

Comment: Oh that makes more sense then, so the meta tag allows the media queries to come to effect. So I'll just investigate the rest of my CSS code to fix anything else. Thanks for the help!